# Youtube playing a video with sound in PWA is not working

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

My app used to be able to play videos with sound inside a PWA environment using the YouTube Iframe API, but in the last few days this is only achieved if there has been a user gesture before. Playing the video muted is allowed, also no errors are produced in the above process.

Comment: Chrome only allow playing sound after a user click / interaction. So in general when I code websites, I ask the user to allow sound before any interaction on the website. But in your case you could display a modal asking to the user for sound or not, or find another UX friendly way to do that. See: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

Comment: This is a PWA environment where sound can be played without a user interaction.

Comment: Yes it is allowed if the PWA is installed. Is your app installed ? :)

Comment: Yes it is installed.

Comment: ok I have to look at this thanks

Comment: did you manage to find any fix for this? @Ben

Answer (score -1):

**This is not allowed anymore in Chrome:**

Chrome's autoplay policies are simple:

> Muted autoplay is always allowed. Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
> The user has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.). On
> desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed,
> meaning the user has previously played video with sound. The user has
> added the site to their home screen on mobile or installed the PWA on
> desktop. Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes
> to allow autoplay with sound.

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

Comment: Please replace image with text. An answer like this is usually downvoted/canceled.

Comment: Agree, please see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2430549).

Comment: I do understand the policy and I oblige to it, although my problem is I cannot autoplay with sound even when the app is installed as a PWA.

Comment: Ok in that case we have to investigate, but I think that my answer can still be reliable for some people having issue with sound, seeing your post

Comment: @Ben thank you for update